# Debugging Issue in visual studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, .net-framework-version

Recently i upgraded my .NET framework from 1.1 to 2.0 (visual studio 2003 to visual studio 2010) and after that I always faced some problem during development while debugging. Somebody facing this before? I can't see what is the data inside some object like following examples (right click and quick watch):

**'objCircle' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.**

**The project currently contains references to more than one version of CDMObjects, a direct reference to version 1.0.4394.17018 and an indirect reference (through 'ProcessFlow.frmBPSOD.m_CopyCircle') to version 1.0.4455.20763. Change the direct reference to use version 1.0.4455.20763 (or higher) of CDMObjects.**

Any solution for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you actually tried removing multiple version references? this can be useful http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/netfxbcl/thread/2828aab2-c8d3-4fae-9950-98c3ca30a63e

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue from time to time. If I go to the Build menu and Clean the solution then Build or Debug it works. Unfortunately, I can't find a solution that fixes this issue once and for all.

I'm hopeful that the following might help:

http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/637576-compiler-error-message-bc32206-indirect-reference-being-made-assembly-dal-ver

I have followed the instructions in the second entry and so far haven't had this issue.

Answer (score 1):

since you are saying to upgraded directly from 2003 to 2010, I would say your real problem isn't what visual studio is telling you but it is about compatibility with some files/resources.